# Adding route value to Url Action in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In this code document.location returns as 'Content/Search/(the searchboxID's value)' . But when I try to make an another search in same page this time document.location return as Content/Search/(the searchboxID's first value)/(the searchboxID's new value) . How can I remove the first value everytime when I search and add $(searchboxID).val() as a route parameter in Url.Action ?

```
<input type="text" id="txtSearch"  class="tftextinput2" name="searchKey" size="21" maxlength="120" value="">
<input type="button" value=">" onclick='redirectOnClick()' class="tfbutton2" id="srcButton">
                

 <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log("result:"+document.getElementById('txtSearch').value)
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var test =document.getElementById('srcButton').addEventListener("click",redirectOnClick);
            var searchboxID = "#txtSearch";
                function redirectOnClick() {
            var routeLink = document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
            console.log("route " + routeLink)
                document.location =   '@Url.Action("Search","Content")' +'/' +$(searchboxID).val();
                
              
                console.log(document.location.pathname);
                $(searchboxID).empty();
               
            //location.reload();
                }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Try `@Url.Action("Search","Content", new { searchTerm = "" })` to generate a url without your search term (use the parameter from your page/search action) - you might want to change to `@Url.RouteUrl` if it does `/Search/Content?searchTerm=''` (I didn't check)

Comment: I think your code should already work. Your Url will be rendered out of your Url Action. Then you just add the segement. Maybe you can log the output of `''@Url.Action("Search", "Content")' +'/' +$(searchboxID).val();'` for us.

Comment: @BeSterDevelopment unfortunately, `@Url.Action(..)` will also add any matching route values from the current page if you don't explicitly specify them.  It's annoying.

Comment: *log the output* - OP already did this: `Content/Search/(the searchboxID's first value)/(the searchboxID's new value)`

Comment: @freedomn-m @Url.Action("Search","Content", new { searchTerm = "" }) this works when I give searchTerm's value something static like "test". But I need $(searchboxID).val()'s value inside Url.Action. I tried to assign this to a variable but it still doesn't work

Comment: I assumed you would keep `+'/' +$(searchboxID).val();`.  Don't mix server-side and client-side code.   `url = '@Url.Action("Search","Content", new { searchTerm = "" })' + '/' + $(searchboxID).val();`

Comment: @freedomn-m it works like a charm! Thank you so much for answering my questions today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the url is

```
Content/Search/(the searchboxID's first value)/(the searchboxID's new value)
```

This is a common issue with using `@Url.Action` where the framework will supply any missing parameters from your current model's properties.

Given a string parameter `searchTerm`,

```
@Url.Action("Search", "Content")
```

becomes the same as

```
@Url.Action("Search", "Content", new { searchTerm = Model.SearchTerm })
```

So you need to explicitly provide that parameter with a blank value so that it is not rendered:

```
@Url.Action("Search", "Content", new { searchTerm = "" })
```

(or `= string.Empty`)

Adding the original javascript component for the new value gives:

```
url = '@Url.Action("Search","Content", new { searchTerm = "" })' + '/' + $(searchboxID).val();
```